# Android why NameSpace app not found

Tags: android, xml

I see below code to add actions on Toolbar from this link

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html

but `app:showAsActions` error, why this **app** not found?

```
<!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

After i searched i added `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` to menu node, but still got Unexpected namespace prefix 'app' for tag item, i know it's a noob question, thanks for you help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Hi Wiiliam, try to reference 'app' attribute with explicitly mentioned package name instead of using 'res-auto'.
 I had this issue once and it got solved with this, want to share may be helpful for you.

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/faisal.Dev.Material_Design"

Comment: Thank you @MFaisalHyder. I make it works. My mistake is i add the menu xml to layout directory. But your comment should works too. This works for me. xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution  :

Have the **right style** selected as defined at manifest

**Manifest**

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**Style**

```
 <style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
```

Select the right title for `showAsAction`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:**yourapp**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      **yourapp**:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
  </menu>
```

## Conclusion :

If you used `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

then you have to used   `yourapp`. in `showAsAction`.

if you used `xmlns:android` then you have used to `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: Thank you, Can u see my edited the bottom picture, i think 'yourapp' is 'app' for my project? module name? is it correct?

Comment: @WilliamHu Yes or simply change `app` with `android` it work also .

Comment: i made it by adding xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" works for me. Not change app to android.

Comment: @WilliamHu see I mention in my first `Solution` `yourapp` see again.

Comment: OK, can you remove your Solution 2, because i tested it doesn't work then i will mark yours as the answer. Also if you can explain what/where to find 'your app' would be better.

Comment: You're awesome, you saved me.